# Moving file under git lfs from one directory to another within the same repository

Tags: git, git-lfs

I have a file that is under `git lfs` control that I want to move from one directory to another within the same git repository.  However, `git mv foo/bar baz/` works for regular files, but does not bring along the LFS state, so I cannot use that.

I.e., I was thinking along the lines of:

1. `git mv foo/biglfs.file bar/`
2. `git lfs track *.file`
3. `git add bar/.gitattributes`
4. `git commit`

But I don’t think that properly updates the LFS file pointers, and I think the first statement will actually add `biglfs.file` to the repo directly, which isn't desirable.

I think I have to manually remove the file from under `git lfs` control, move the file, and then re-add it.  But that strikes me as a lot of work, so surely there's an easy and direct way to do this?

Comment: You only need to adjust the `.gitattributes` file line for each renamed file. There probably *should* be a `git lfs mv` command that would do this for you, but apparently there isn't: see [this closed issue](https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/issues/2069).

Comment: That does not work.  Moving the `.gitattributes` does not notify git lfs of the new file location.

Comment: I know `git mv` doesn't handle this. I said there *should be* a `git lfs mv` command to do it for you. But apparently the Git-LFS folks don't agree and just closed the issue.